# Command to browse online archives on CLI

Tags: command-line, shell, webarchive

Is there a shell command which lets us go through archive like http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/hive/ through CLI ?

Some command which lets us perform functions of atleast one of 
ls and cd, tree, find .

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there a very obvious solution ?

Answer (score 0):

lynx(1) should do the job.  If you want to download the whole site to local disk, `wget -r` is your friend.